# Camelot Pdf Extraction FAIL parsing

Tags: python, pdf, python-camelot

Im getting a problem with Camelot library

Im extracting data from PDF, my code is running "ok" for previous 23 page, but for this case its failing to parse text/table ending

I suppose the problem is the string is so long reaching table border

Also tried "stream" but got worst results

PDF Source Data

[image: pdf]

PDF Output LAYOUT

[image: layout]

My output parsed is like

```
"ALT4945\n24 V"
"70\/140 A   ALT5860\n12 V\n90 A"
```

Desired output should be

```
"ALT4945\n24 V 70\/140 A"
"ALT5860\n12 V\n90 A"
```

My first code that work correctly for previous page is

```
tables = camelot.read_pdf("CROSSREFERENCE.pdf", pages=wPAGES, flavor="lattice")
```

From the website Camelot Doc https://camelot-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/api.html I get that posible configuration on pdf parser.

```
"" PARAMS for lattice
line_scale  (default: 15)
copy_text   ((default: None))
shift_text  (default: ['l', 't'])
line_tol    (default: 2)
joint_tol   (default: 2)
threshold_blocksize   (default: 15)
threshold_constant    (default: -2)
iterations   (default: 0)
resolution   (default: 300)
"""
```

Then I get that problem, tried to solve "playing" with more params, but didnt found the winner

```
tables = camelot.read_pdf("CROSSREFERENCE.pdf", pages=wPAGES, flavor="lattice", split_text=True, resolution=720, line_scale=250, line_tol=3, joint_tol=3, threshold_blocksize=15)

tables = camelot.read_pdf("CROSSREFERENCE.pdf", pages=wPAGES, flavor="lattice", split_text=True, resolution=720, line_scale=250, line_tol=1, joint_tol=1, threshold_blocksize=3)
```

Can I get some advice about params to avoid that??

Thanks

edit1:
PDF source : https://www.siom.it/images/catalogo-motorini-alter.pdf
(Page 24)

Comment: Can you attach the file or only this page, in order to make us able to perform some tests?

Comment: @Anakin87 edited question qith pdf url

Comment: It seems really difficult to obtain the result which you want.
Maybe for such cases, you can think of some content postprocessing...

Comment: @Anakin87 thanks for waste your time, im actually doing post processing, but cant do it if parser is doing wrongly. I expected some param can help to avoid that problem

Comment: Your approach of expecting the library to reliably split where you want the splits is wrong. This just is not how PDF works.

Comment: @fpbhb so what do you reccomend to extract pdf info? I expected that camelot library work like it should work and it works for almost all pages. I "resolv" the problem with post process text and discard errors

Comment: The library’s heuristics for properly joining/separating text runs are literally just that: heuristics. PDF generators produce all kinds of weird text runs because of kerning, spacing etc. You’ll always have to check for errors and post-process based on content, or optimize heuristics yourself for your specific case based on more detail from the PDF (page coordinates of text runs, distances, font metrics ...). PDF is a hi-fi display format, not a data container.

Answer (score 5):

### Tested Solution

```
tables = camelot.read_pdf('./catalogo-motorini-alter.pdf', pages='24', 
                           flavor='stream', columns=['300'], split_text=True)
```

The output of `tables[0].df` is following:

```
                                         0                                                  1
0                CATALOGO SIOM ALTERNATORI                   BOSCH  \nBOSCH  \nBOSCH  \nBOSCH
1                       ALT4800\n12 V\n65A                                ALT4830\n12 V\n70 A
2   IMPIANTO : BOSCH\nCOD.OEM : 0120489186             IMPIANTO : BOSCH\nCOD.OEM : 0120488172
3           APPLICAZIONI :\n OPEL VAUXHALL                     APPLICAZIONI :\n OPEL VAUXHALL
4                      ALT4840\n12 V\n70 A                                ALT4890\n12 V\n90 A
5   IMPIANTO : BOSCH\nCOD.OEM : 0120488186             IMPIANTO : BOSCH\nCOD.OEM : 0123315500
6           APPLICAZIONI :\n OPEL VAUXHALL                             APPLICAZIONI :\n IVECO
7                      ALT4900\n12 V\n90 A                            ALT4940\n24 V\n70/140 A
8   IMPIANTO : BOSCH\nCOD.OEM : 0123320009             IMPIANTO : BOSCH\nCOD.OEM : 0120689535
9           APPLICAZIONI :\n AUDI SKODA VW  APPLICAZIONI :\n DROGMOLLER KASSBOHRER MERCEDE...
10                 ALT4945\n24 V\n70/140 A                                ALT5860\n12 V\n90 A
11  IMPIANTO : BOSCH\nCOD.OEM : 0120689541             IMPIANTO : BOSCH\nCOD.OEM : 0120450011
12      APPLICAZIONI :\n MAN MERCEDES BENZ                          APPLICAZIONI :\n CHRYSLER
13                     ALT6600\n12 V\n90 A                                ALT6610\n24 V\n80 A
14  IMPIANTO : BOSCH\nCOD.OEM : 0124325058             IMPIANTO : BOSCH\nCOD.OEM : 0124555001
15            APPLICAZIONI :\n FIAT LANCIA                     APPLICAZIONI :\n MERCEDES BENZ
16                                     Pag                                                .24
```

#### Explanation

From the [docs](https://camelot-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/how-it-works.html#stream) it seems that `stream` parser fits better than `lattice` for the shared document:

> `Stream` can be used to parse tables that have whitespaces between cells
> to simulate a table structure.

And for the cases when a `stream` parser finds incorrect columns separators you can specify them by hand in `columns` argument ([details](https://camelot-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/advanced.html#specify-column-separators)). Then `split_text` option [says](https://camelot-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/advanced.html#split-text-along-separators) to split text with those columns:)

### Discussions

Although [fpbhb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2278030/fpbhb) criticized **scraping** PDFs in comments, I would be rather optimistic in your specific case. The document you shared is well structured. So I would definitely try to parse it. But the point of [fpbhb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2278030/fpbhb) still correct that it is *heuristic*. So **additional precautions are required.**

I suggest you to use [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html) to test what you got from `camelot`.

You can use the code below as a starting point:

```
import re
import logging

def test_tables(tables):
    # headers
    HEADER_L = re.compile('^CATALOGO SIOM ALTERNATORI$')
    HEADER_R = re.compile('^BOSCH  \nBOSCH  \nBOSCH  \nBOSCH$')

    # main cell rows
    CELL_ROWS = [
        re.compile('^ALT\d{4,6}?\n(12|14|24|28) ?V\n\d{2,3}(/\d{2,3})? ?A$'),
        re.compile('^IMPIANTO : .*?\nCOD.OEM : [\dA]{9,10}$'),
        re.compile('^APPLICAZIONI :(\n[A-Z \.-]*)?$')
    ]

    # bottom line should be Pag.##
    PAGE = re.compile('^Pag.\d{1,3}$')

    for ti, table in enumerate(tables):
        rows = table.df.to_numpy()
        # test headers
        if not HEADER_L.match(rows[0, 0]):
            logging.warning('tables[{}].df.iloc[0][0]: HEADER_L != {}'.format(ti, rows[0, 0]))
        if not HEADER_R.match(rows[0, 1]):
            logging.warning('tables[{}].df.iloc[0][1]: HEADER_R != {}'.format(ti, rows[0, 1]))

        # test bottom line
        page_str = ''.join(rows[-1])
        if not PAGE.match(page_str):
            logging.warning('tables[{}].df.iloc[-1]: PAGE != {}'.format(ti, page_str))

        # test cells
        for idx, row in enumerate(rows[1:-1]):
            row_idx = idx % 3
            pattern = CELL_ROWS[row_idx]
            if not pattern.match(row[0]):
                logging.warning('tables[{}].df.iloc[{}][0]: ROW {} != {}'.format(ti, idx+1, row_idx, row[0]))
            if not pattern.match(row[1]):
                logging.warning('tables[{}].df.iloc[{}][1]: ROW {} != {}'.format(ti, idx+1, row_idx, row[1]))
```

### Test first 24 pages

```
pages_till_24 = ','.join([str(i) for i in range(1,25)])
tables = camelot.read_pdf('./catalogo-motorini-alter.pdf', pages=pages_till_24, 
                          flavor='stream', columns=['300'], split_text=True) 
test_tables(tables)
```

It gives only one insignificant warning (extra whitespace)

```
WARNING:root:tables[8].df.iloc[7][1]: ROW 0 != ALT122300
12 V 
45 A
```

#### Conclusion

Well, It looks like you can be happy, because it seems to work and you have code to test other pages. Good Luck:)

Comment: Wow thanks for your question and your time. I will check it tomorrow. I start my project with flavor="stream" but sometimes it change the order of strings. I will try with you params running over all pages. But my project is finished, post processing text with a bit of auto-learning and I discard errors to /dev/null you know what I means?

Comment: Hey @MrPisarik I tested your code and seems to run ok!! With "auto-learning" I means to get the manufacter string as key in dict, detected by regex, and using keys to parse future inputs string

Comment: Brilliantly answered!